# Why does my nodelist contain 0 items when console logged from my JS file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, console, nodelist

The JS code that I'm concerned with is this:

```
 const modals=document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
    const modalsArray=[...modals];
    console.log(modalsArray);
    
    document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      if (e.target.classList.contains("item")) {
        itemIndex=e.target.classList.item(1);
        const modals=document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
        const modalsArray=[...modals];
        console.log(itemIndex);
        console.log(modalsArray);
        modalsArray.filter(function (modal) {
          if (modal.classList.item(1)===itemIndex) {
            modal.classList.add('on');
            modalContainer.classList.remove('off');
            modalContainer.classList.add('on');
          }
        })
      }
    });


const arrow=document.querySelectorAll('.arrow');
const arrowArray=[...arrow];
console.log(arrowArray);
```

**Whenever I console log the modalsArray or the arrowArray from my JS file, the array shows up empty**. But I found that if I write out the code from scratch in the console to make the arrays, then all the items in the array show up properly.

So why is this happening? Why is an empty array currently showing up on my console? Does it have to do with scope or something?

When I put the modalsArray inside the eventlistener, and I click the respective target, an array will show properly and the rest of the code in that eventlistener works properly.

I'm noticing the same thing with the arrowArray and realized these two elements are having the same problem. I figured I should ask then because something is definitely up.

So why is an empty array showing up for both of these elements as seen in the image?

Comment: `generateHTML` is asynchronous. You aren’t waiting for it to finish before trying to select the elements it creates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your console statements are executing even before the data is fetched. I chained them in another "then" function (promise chaining) as follows. This way your console statements run after your results are parsed to hmtl.

https://jsfiddle.net/v83zqofp/1/

```
function generateHTML (data) {
  fetchData(data)
  .then(function(data){
    let results=data.results;
    return results.map(function(result,index){
      -------------
      main.lastElementChild.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', html);
      modalContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', overlayHtml);      
    })
  }).then (function (data) {
      const modals=document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
      const modalsArray=[...modals];
      console.log(modalsArray);

      const arrow=document.querySelectorAll('.arrow');
      const arrowArray=[...arrow];
      console.log(arrowArray);
  })
}
```

Comment: @AmandeepPasricha When you called "generateHTML", it first calls fetch data method and waits (runs remaning code because it's asynchronous) till it gets the resuts then executes the code under "return results.map()..." to create DOM elements. So in your inital code your console statments ran in this wait period. That's why they were logging empty arrays.

Comment: @AmandeepPasricha If you wish to understand how "asynchronous" calls work, here is a good read https://eloquentjavascript.net/11_async.html